# sql query to fetch datewise count from table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

`Table name = Master`

I need an sql query which fetches a datewise result from table.

Data is present in my database as displayed below.

```
 date                   copiesbooked             surveycount
13-03-2015                  700                      raj
13-03-2015                  700                      raj
13-03-2015                  700                      raj
13-03-2015                  700                      raj

13-03-2015                  701                      raj
13-03-2015                  701                      raj
13-03-2015                  701                      raj
13-03-2015                  701                      raj

13-03-2015                  702                      akash
13-03-2015                  702                      akash
13-03-2015                  702                      akash
13-03-2015                  702                      akash

14-03-2015                  703                      sunil
14-03-2015                  703                     sunil
14-03-2015                  703                      sunil
14-03-2015                  703                      sunil

15-03-2015                  704                      raj
15-03-2015                  704                      raj
15-03-2015                  704                      raj
15-03-2015                  704                      raj
```

In the above table, there are 3 copies booked on 13-03-2015 named 700,701,702 and only 2 surveyor worked raj and akash....hence surveycount is 2.

Again, there are 1 copiesbooked on 14-03-2015 named 703 and only 1 surveyor worked sunil ...hence surveycount is 1...like wise...

**I need output like below**

```
 date            copiesbooked             surveycount
13-03-2015            3                       2
14-03-2015            1                       1
15-03-2015            1                       1
```

Could you please help to make the sql query for getting such output...

below is my query which i tried...but this does not get distinct count of  copiesbooked and surveycount column..my query gets all rows group by date..

```
select date,
count(copiesbooked) as copiesbooked,
count(surveycount) as  surveycount from master 
group by date
```

Comment: Where is your attempt?

Comment: plz seee...i post my query..and try to help ...me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`group by` the `date` column is what you want. use `Distinct` to show unique count of entries

```
select date,
count(distinct copiesbooked) as copiesbooked,
count(distinct surveycount) as  surveycount from master 
group by date
```

Comment: but my copiesbooked column and surveycount column has same data multiple times....like above table i shown in my question....so your query get count of all rows date wise.....

Comment: plz see my data in my question and my output table......bcoz in my table same data occur multiple  times ...i need date wise but distinct count of all column

Comment: @sunilsatpute see my edit . just add `distinct` keyword to count then it will give you unique count of entries